# Why am I receiving the following error on minify "Unexpected identifer 'trytoCatch'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have made an update to my script.js and I would like to minify it using "minify" in node js.
On the command line I type: minify script.js > script.min.js and I am receiving the following error:
/node_modules/bin/minify.js:3
import "tryToCatch" from "try-to-catch"
Unexpected identifier

[image: Node error]

Comment: Show what `node -v` returns

Comment: How old is your Node.js version?

Comment: My node version is 12.6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating node version to >=16 should work:
[image]

Comment: Yep, had to install a new version of node js